# How to get the sum of the adjacent data with dataframe in multiple partitions scala/spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I hava a DataFrame and I want to get the sum of adjacent data,I use window function,but I find when I use window function,all of the data are collected in one partition.How to get the sum of the adjacent data with dataframe in multiple partitions?
this is my code:

```
val arr = Array(1, 7, 3, 3, 5,21, 7, 3, 9, 10)
    var df = sc.parallelize(arr,5).toDF("value")
   val w=Window.rowsBetween(-1,0)
   df= df.withColumn("nextValue",first(col("value")).over(w)).withColumn("sum",col("value")+col("nextValue"))
    println(df.rdd.getNumPartitions)
    df.show()
    //get the data'number of each partition
      df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{
        (partIdx,iter) => {
          var part_map = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int]()
          while(iter.hasNext){
            var part_name = "part_" + partIdx;
            if(part_map.contains(part_name)) {
              var ele_cnt = part_map(part_name)
              part_map(part_name) = ele_cnt + 1
            } else {
              part_map(part_name) = 1
            }
            iter.next()
          }
          part_map.iterator

        }
      }.collect.foreach(println)
```

This is my expect result:

```
+-----+---------+---+
|value|nextValue|sum|
+-----+---------+---+
|    1|        1|  2|
|    7|        1|  8|
|    3|        7| 10|
|    3|        3|  6|
|    5|        3|  8|
|   21|        5| 26|
|    7|       21| 28|
|    3|        7| 10|
|    9|        3| 12|
|   10|        9| 19|
+-----+---------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `sliding`:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

df.as[Int].rdd.sliding(2).map(_.sum).toDF
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can try with an column:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    var df = sc.parallelize(List(1, 7, 3, 3, 5, 21, 7, 3, 9, 10).zipWithIndex, 5).toDF("value", "id")
    df=df.withColumn("nextValue",first(df("value")).over(Window.orderBy("id").rowsBetween(-1,0)))
    df=df.withColumn("sum",df("value")+df("nextValue"))
    df.select("value", "nextValue", "sum").show()
```

Result:

```
+-----+---------+---+
|value|nextValue|sum|
+-----+---------+---+
|    1|        1|  2|
|    7|        1|  8|
|    3|        7| 10|
|    3|        3|  6|
|    5|        3|  8|
|   21|        5| 26|
|    7|       21| 28|
|    3|        7| 10|
|    9|        3| 12|
|   10|        9| 19|
+-----+---------+---+
```

Comment: In your way ,all of the data are collected in one partition ,I want to calculate in multiple partition